# PHP mySQL numRows() usage and errors?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

I have the following code that I am using to check for constraints on a database(for a class). U am trying to get the number of rows returned by the query and I keep getting the same error on the line

```
$count1= $ires1->numRows(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
```

Error:

```
> Call to a member function numRows() on a non-object
```

I've been pulling my hair out because my other functions similar to this one work fine, this is the only function that doesn't work. Is there something that stands out in this one?

The argument $db is just the connection to my database, `pno` is an integer and the `essn` is text.. So I'm not sure what I am doing wrong..

```
<?php
function submitCheck($db){
    $essn= $_POST['essn'];
    $pno=$_POST['pno'];

    $query1 = "select * from works_on where pno=? and essn=?";
    $types1 = array('integer','text');
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare($query1, $types1, MDB2_PREPARE_MANIP);

    if (MDB2::isError($stmt1)) {
        print("bad prepared statement:" . $stmt->getMessage());
    }

    $queryargs1 = array($pno, $essn);
    $ires1 = $stmt1->execute($queryargs1);
    $count1= $ires1->numRows(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    //print("The project number entered was $count1[pno]");
    if(!(count($count1)==0)){
        print("The employee is already part of this project! If you want to update the hours, please select update!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$ires1`? Is it possible the query fails and `$stmt1->execute` returns some error value instead? (like `false`, or `null`)

Comment: I think it does return a null value, which is why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

```
$count1 = $stmt1->rowCount();
```

`$ires1` is not an `Object`, but a `boolean`, as stated in [PHP PDOStatement::rowcount](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) documentation.

A warning though, from the PHP.net site:

> If the last SQL statement executed by
>   the associated `PDOStatement` was a
>   `SELECT` statement, some databases may
>   return the number of rows returned by
>   that statement. However, this
>   behaviour is not guaranteed for all
>   databases and should not be relied on
>   for portable applications.

There you have their suggested solution too:

> For most databases,
>   `PDOStatement::rowCount()` does not
>   return the number of rows affected by
>   a `SELECT` statement. Instead, use
>   `PDO::query()` to issue a `SELECT
>   COUNT(*)` statement with the same
>   predicates as your intended SELECT
>   statement, then use
>   `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()` to
>   retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned. Your application can then
>   perform the correct action."

I did not know and I couldn't find information on method `numRows`, so that's as far as I can go. Good luck!

Comment: @Paul, if it helped then you should at least add an _upvote_ to this answer and if it ultimately answered your question then mark this answer as the accepted answer